# Displaying All Result in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

i have wroten a very simple prolog. I compiled it in swi-prolog and consult a very simple question. Here is my prolog.

```
isa(bird, animal).
isa(robin, bird).
isa(fish, animal).
isa(cod, fish).
isa(mammal, animal).
isa(lion, mammal).
isa(horse, mammal).
isa(bat, mammal).
isa(pipistrelle, bat).
isa1(X,Y) :- isa(X,Y).
isa1(X,Z) :- isa(X,Y), isa1(Y,Z).
```

My question is , when i run the following question;

```
isa(pipistrelle, O).
```

swi-prolog shows only the following ;

```
O = bat.
```

I want to display all possibilities like :

```
O = bat;
O = mammal;
O = animal
```

Could you help me at this point , thanks.

Comment: My mistake , i should had to run isa1(pipistrelle,O) question and put ; after for each answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `isa/2` predicate but you should be calling instead the `isa1/2` predicate, which is the one implementing the transitive closure for the *isa* relation:

```
?- isa1(pipistrelle, O).
O = bat ;
O = mammal ;
O = animal ;
false.
```